# Confused about references and pointers in my BFS tile class

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, tile, breadth-first-search

I am currently coding a Tile class to be used in my BFS algorithm. I need a `cameFrom` variable that will keep track of where the tiles came from as I traverse a grid. It should not be initialized at the start as we do not know where it came from at the start. As I run through my BFS algorithm, it will continuously update.

```
Error 1 error C2758: 'Tile::cameFrom' : a member of reference type must be initialized
```

Anyone know what is wrong?

Here is my Tile.hpp:

```
#ifndef _TILE_H
#define _TILE_H

class Tile
{
    public:

        Tile(int x, int y);

        ~Tile();

        int GetX();

        int GetY();

        bool IsWall();

        bool IsVisited();

        void SetCameFrom(Tile& cameFrom);

        Tile& GetCameFrom();

        void ToggleWall();

        void ToggleVisited();

    private:

        int x;
        int y;
        bool isWall;
        bool isVisited;
        Tile& cameFrom;

};

#endif
```

My Tile.cpp:

```
#include "Tile.hpp"


Tile::Tile(int x, int y) {

    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->isWall = false;
    this->isVisited = false;

}

Tile::~Tile() {}

int Tile::GetX() {

    return x;

}

int Tile::GetY() {

    return y;

}

bool Tile::IsWall() {

    return isWall;

}

bool Tile::IsVisited() {

    return isVisited;

}

void Tile::SetCameFrom(Tile& cameFrom) {

    this->cameFrom = cameFrom;

}

Tile& Tile::GetCameFrom() {

    return cameFrom;

}

void Tile::ToggleWall() {

    isWall = !isWall;

}

void Tile::ToggleVisited() {

    isVisited = true;

}
```

Comment: References must be initialized. In your case, I'd use a pointer instead, because a pointer can be null.

Comment: I suggest using a pointer instead of a reference; but that doesn't mean you should change the parameter of SetCameFrom to a pointer as well.

Comment: Oh okay, so with a pointer, does this mean in my cpp file I need to change a few things? First, in `SetCameFrom`, I have to assign the pointer` cameFrom` with the address of the argument `cameFrom` right? So I would have `this->cameFrom = &cameFrom;`. Secondly, in the function `GetCameFrom()`, I have to redefine the function output as `Tile*& Tile::GetCameFrom() {` because `cameFrom` is now a pointer? Or should I just return the pointer instead of a reference to the pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly reference must be initialized, so you would have to set it in the constructor. Secondly you can't re-assign reference, so your `SetCameFrom` function won't work. Use pointers for this.

```
Tile * cameFrom;
```

But it's also good to initialize pointer to 0 (or nullptr in C++11) in the constructor.

```
Tile::Tile(int p_x, int p_y):
    x(p_x), 
    y(p_y),
    cameFrom(0),
    isWall(false),
    isVisited(false)
{
}
```

Comment: Oh okay, this means in my cpp file I need to change a few things. First, in `SetCameFrom`, I have to assign the pointer `cameFrom` with the address of the argument `cameFrom` right? So I would have `this->cameFrom = &cameFrom;`. Secondly, in the function `GetCameFrom()`, I have to redefine the function output as `Tile*& Tile::GetCameFrom() {` because `cameFrom` is now a pointer? Or should I just return the pointer instead of a reference to the pointer?

Comment: @JustinLiang 1. Technically you could use `&` to obtain address of `cameFrom` parameter, but it will be more clean if you modify a function to accept pointer: `void SetCameFrom(Tile * cameFrom);`. 2. You should just return pointer `Tile* Tile::GetCameFrom()`. When you return a reference to a pointer, a caller can modify to what `cameFrom` points to (because you return a reference to a pointer and reference behaves like alias of referenced variable). It's effectively like you would make `cameFrom` variable public.

Answer (score 1):

*It should not be initialized at the start as we do not know where it came from at the start*

Then you can only use pointers as references must be initialized to something. Always ask following three questions when you are stuck over the choice between *pointer* OR *reference*.

- Do I need something for which I need to perform initialization at the point of it's declaration.
- Do I need to make this to refer to some other variable (assign) in it's lifetime.
- Do I need to make that object point to NULL.

If answer to any of the question is Yes, then choose pointer else reference.